# Plot and Save png plots using ggplot2 of all columns of a dataframe individually in R

Tags: loops, ggplot2, graph

I would like to plot a scatterplot for all variables in my dataset. I use the ggplot2 library and I want to save each plot individually in .png format.

As an example, I use mtcars data which is compatible with my original data. I fixed the mpg variable and oscillates the others.

I tried to adapt with the other topics of the forum, but I was not successful. I've used this code and other approaches, but now I'm not successful, as the saved files are empty.

Thanks for any progress

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars

for (i in 1:6) {
plotname = paste("dispersion_", names(df)[i],sep = "") #name file
png(paste0(plotname, ".png"),  width = 10, height = 8, units = 'in', res = 300) # save

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=mpg, y=df[,i])) +
    geom_line( color="grey") +
    geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#3189cc", size=3) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
g
dev.off()

print(names(df)[i])
}
```

Comment: Chang `g` to `print(g)`.

Comment: Hi, using print(g) only displays the graph, but the save is still empty. I added print(names(df)[i]) just for checking.

Comment: Odd. That change definitely worked when I ran on my system. Glad you found an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function used to save and it solved the problem. But I didn't understand why the png function didn't work. With ggsave the problem was easily solved.

```
 for (i in 1:4) {
    plotname = paste("dispersion_", names(df)[i],sep = "") #name file
    ggplot(df, aes(x=mpg, y=df[,i])) +
        geom_line( color="grey") +
        geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#3189cc", size=3) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
    
    print(names(df)[i])
    ggsave(paste0(plotname,".png"))
    }
```